# Access Spring boot component in ExchangeFilterFunction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multithreading, spring-webclient

I am preparing ExchangeFilterFunction using below class,

```
@Configuration    
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class WebClientConfiguration {
    
      private final SessionContextService sessionContextService;
     @Bean
      public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        return builder.filter(getFilterWithHeader()).build();
      }
 
    private ExchangeFilterFunction getFilterWithHeader() {
    
        return (ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) ->
            next.exchange(
                    ClientRequest.from(request)
                        .header(
                            "HeaderKey",
                            sessionContextService.getHeaderValue().isPresent()
                                ? sessionContextService.getHeaderValue().get()
                                : null)
                        .build())
                .doOnNext(
                    (ClientResponse response) -> {
                      var headerValues = response.headers().asHttpHeaders().get("headerKey");
                      if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(headerValues)) {
                        sessionContextService.storeHeaderValue(headerValues.get(0));
                      }
                    });
      }
}
```

Here, sessionContextService is a spring boot component where I would like to store the header value from response and add to next request. Attaching above filter to the web client using below method.

This is working fine local, but when I deploy in environments, I get this error,

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request
> found:    Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual
> web request,      or processing a request outside of the originally
> receiving thread?     If you are actually operating within a web request
> and still receive this message,   your code is probably running
> outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet:   In this case,
> use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

It is clear from the error that the bean sessionContextService is not accessible within ExchangeFilterFunction context, but could not find an efficient solution. I need to store this header value to the component sessionContextService as it in turn stores it in a redis session for the future access of the values.

Could anyone suggest a solution to handle this scenario?